# Структура данных для оптимального хранения множественных связей

Tags: структуры-данных, память

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли структура в которой можно оптимально хранить связи между элементами без больших затрат памяти? Данные могут храниться на жестком диске или распределенно. Просто на каждый элемент структуры будет приходиться по 500-800 млн связей и будут добавляться все новые связи с ростом количества элементов структуры.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO это все сугубо теоретические измышления.

--

Даже уменьшив общий объем данных (ну, не одни же связи хранить?) на пару порядков все равно получим:

10^18 Byte ~ 10^6 HDD ~ **10^8 USD** (это для самых дешевых).

Другая сторона проблемы:

если даже отбросить СУБД и заливать данные со скоростью 10^8 Byte/sec (очень приличная скорость просто для генерации чего либо внутри узла) и размазать работу по 1000 узлам получим **10^7 секунд** (всего-то 115 суток)...

[@finder39459](/users/14520/finder39459), *на кого работаете?*

Answer (score 0):

Используйте базу данных, ваши данные не поместятся в память.

Смотрите, почему не поместятся: у вас у элемента структуры порядка 10^9 связей, значит, в памяти 10^9 структур. Если каждая связь занимает хоть один байт, у вас расход памяти лишь на связи будет 10^9 * 10^9 байт, то есть 10^18 байт, то есть порядка эксабайта! Вы знаете систему, которая выделит вам столько памяти?

Comment: не обязательно оперативная память, сейчас уточню вопрос

Comment: @finder39459: Ну так, я ж пишу, используйте базу данных.

Comment: реляционную?

Comment: @finder39459: Да в принципе любую, (1) которая поддерживает данные ваших объёмов, (2) которую вы сможете подключить к своему языку программирования, (3) которая по результатам ваших тестов окажется достаточно быстрой для ваших задач.

Comment: что же это за данные такие? может для них существуют более оптимальные структуры.

Кстати, на одну связь можно использовать один бит. Но это не сильно уменьшит объем.

Comment: @KoVadim что то типа гиперграфа. Наверно придется создавать связи лениво если ничего не найду.

Comment: @KoVadim: Это даст выигрыш только если среднее количество связей на элемент больше 1/8 от общего количества элементов. И да, это всё равно не сильно поможет, всего 1 десятичный порядок.

Comment: Нужно посмотреть, сколько там элементов вообще. Может быть будет дешевле хранить "отсутствующие связи" или паковать связи, например в виде бинарного дерева.

Comment: @avp: И правда. :-) Опубликуете ваши расчёты как ответ?

Answer (score 0):

[Декартовы деревья по неявному ключу + сжатие пространства](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161093/)

[Структура Radix Tree для сжатия данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141145/)